# Managing TCP Sockets in Java Enterprise Edition

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, tcp, jca

I'm trying to port some Java SE code to a Java EE Server offering - however I am a massive n00b when it comes to JEE - apparently I need to build a Resource Adapter to access a Socket - I have bought several books and training DVD's - none of them cover using TCP Sockets in JEE or building a custom RA.

I'd like to support Raw Socket support rather than rely on Customers deploying MOM's to use JMS (nature of the server app - most still use TCP/IP communication).

Can someone please offer some sensible advice?

Thanks :)

Comment: what server will you be using? if it's glassfish take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-6594/inst_tcpip-jca-rt0_t/index.html

Comment: I'm using GlassFish for Development and Testing purposes but it really needs to be flexible enough to work on a variety of JEE App Servers.